# Подключение библиотеки Boost в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: boost, lib, библиотеки, visual-studio

Помогите!
Скачал библиотеку Boost с оф. сайта самой последней версии (`boost_1_56_0`) и не могу подключить её к проекту!
Подскажите, как это сделать.

Делал так:

```
1. Свойства проекта -> Компановщик -> Общие -> Дополнительные каталоги библиотек: 
            H:\boost_1_56_0;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

2. Свойства проекта -> C/C++ -> Общие -> Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов:               
            H:\boost_1_56_0\boost;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

Потом надо добавить библиотеки в `Компановщик -> Ввод -> Дополнительные зависимости: "там, где лежит Boost\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib"`, хорошо!
Но у меня в структуре папок нету папки stage, а в ней тем более папки lib!
Что делать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Папка `boost_1_56_0` содержит следующие папки:

```
boost
doc
libs
more
status
tools
```

Comment: Хм. Может быть, вам надо ещё что-то скомпилировать, тогда `lib` и появится?

Comment: что именно скомпилировать? Готовую библиотеку? 
После всей этой возни пытаюсь написать #include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>, а компилятор пишет: не удаётся открыть источник файла <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>.
Ахинея какая-то.

Comment: @rekrut1: А в чём выражается «не работает»?

Comment: @VladD пытаюсь написать #include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>, а компилятор пишет: не удаётся открыть источник файла <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp> и include красным подчёркивает.

Comment: @rekrut1: Хорошо, а файл `H:\boost_1_56_0\boost\boost\mpl\for_each.hpp` существует?

Обратит внимание на двойной `boost`.